# Angular CLI install issue on Mac

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to install old angular cli version but it's always showing 6.0.3 version.

[image]

Why it's showing @angular-devkit/core error version ? Do you have any idea?

npm version  6.0.1
node version v8.11.2

Comment: You need to downgrade your node version in order to install OLD angular cli version

Comment: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.8

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to install a specific version of ng-cli (e.g. v1.6.3):

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.3
```

You can see the available versions with the following command:

```
npm view @angular/cli
```

Comment: Have you checked official documentation for angular/cli? which clearly stated that for angular v6  you need node version 8

Comment: I don't think you can install OLD angular/cli on node version 8 or above

Comment: This is not a deal for him given he wants to install a lower version of ng-cli.

Comment: That's what I am trying to say

Comment: Yes, and I tell you there is no need to downgrade node. I'm currently with this configuration without any problems: Angular CLI: 1.6.2
Node: 9.10.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.7

Comment: then you must be using NVM

Comment: Nope, I'm not using it. :)

Comment: amazing, how's it possible :|